# Confused on a LINQ where clause

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

```
public ViewResult List(string category, int page = 1) 
{
    ProductsListViewModel viewModel = new ProductsListViewModel
    {
        Products = repository.Products
            .Where(p => category == null || p.Category == category)
            ...........
```

The line : `.Where(p => category == null || p.Category == category)` is a little confusing to me. The logic is : "If category is null, then only select the selected category".
This is from a book, but is this the best way to write this?
It's saying the category can be "null OR an category value". So if category contains a value, it will use that value to select the items and not null (null selects all items).
I wrote this which is kind of useless but works and makes its clearer :

```
.Where(p => category == null ? category == null :
                               p.Category == category)
```

Am I getting this logic right?

Comment: I don't think yours makes it any clearer. Perhaps if you replaced the second use of `category==null` with true it might be...

Comment: Like Jon said, it allows the category to be optional. It'll short-circuit and select all if category is null.

Comment: Thanks all, . . yes, looking at it with short-circuit in mind makes it clear now. I guess I was thinking it needed to be conditional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's basically allowing the category filter to be optional - if the `category` parameter is non-null, then it has to match whatever you're looking at. Otherwise, just include all categories.

Answer (score 1):

```
.Where(p => category == null || p.Category == category)
```

There are two parts here, connected by an OR, which means *one of them* must be `true`, to result in `true`:

```
category == null
```

The category given was null

```
p.Category == category
```

The category in question matches the category given

So it will select a `p`, if either the category given was null, or it matched the category of `p`.

Answer (score 1):

```
.Where(p => category == null || p.Category == category)
```

will be translated to SQL query something like this (not exactly):

```
where null is null or Category == null    // When not specified, show all because, null IS null = true
// or
where 'someCategory' is null or Category == 'SomeCategoy'  // filter by some category
```

Ternary will return a bool, and not a condition to construct SQL query

```
category == null ? category == null : p.Category == category
```